# How to update a model of directive 1 from directive 2 and see changes on view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives and i want to update model (`this` in controllerAs syntax) in directive 1.

```
// Linkbox
SApp.directive('linkBox', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$templateCache', '$state', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache, $state, $timeout){
    return {
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.setBoxTitle = function(title){
                vm.boxTitle = title;
                console.log('setBoxTitle', title); // returns correct value!
                // also tried this:
                // $timeout(function(){
                //  vm.boxTitle = title;
                //  console.log('title of box', vm.boxTitle);
                // }, 1);
            }
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'linkbox.html',
        controllerAs: 'lbCtrl',
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            console.log('link');
        }
    };
}]);

// SubCategories linkbox
SApp.directive('subCategories', ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$templateCache', '$state', function($rootScope, $compile, $templateCache, $state){
    return {
        require: 'linkBox',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, lbCtrl) {
            lbCtrl.setBoxTitle('Title of box...');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Using directives:

```
<div link-box sub-categories ></div>
```

This is the view (**linkbox.html**)

```
<div class="linkbox">
  <h3 class="title" ng-bind="lbCtrl.boxTitle"></h3>
  <ul> <li> <a>...</a> </li> </ul>
</div>
```

Communication of directives is ok and console.log returns correct value, But I see no change in view. Can you help please?

**Update:**

When i manually set `controller.boxTitle = 'A title'` in link function of linkBox directive, View has updated value. So there is no problem in html code.

---

**Problem solved.**

There was another usage of `link-box` directive like this:

```
<div link-box sub-categories ></div>
<div class="area" link-box related-searchs ></div>
```

In second use of link-box, I just added another directive without setting title. I should use isolate scope to prevent colision between models of different modules.

Comment: Did you try $scope.$apply after updating the value .

Comment: @ashfaq.p Just tested it (after `vm.boxTitle = title` ). => Error: $digest already in progress

Comment: then you can try out $timeout.

Comment: @ashfaq.p Not worked :(

Comment: Create a fiddle or plunker and i will help.

Comment: @ashfaq.p Check this please: http://jsbin.com/celeci/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

As per code in the jsbin , ng-template has been used , if this is the case then you have provide an id or class for the template as below id="myTpl", and include that using ng-include directive

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTpl">
    <div class="box linkbox" >
      <div class="inr">
        <div class="content">
            <h3 class="title" ng-bind="lbCtrl.boxTitle"></h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a>link 1</a></li>
                <li><a>link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
</script>


<div link-box sub-categories  ng-include="'myTpl'"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/baneyezezu/1/edit?html,js,output